# How do I express how precise the results of my simulation are?

Tags: confidence-interval

I am working on an [UNO Simulator](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/should-i-ask-a-new-uno-question-and-if-so-how-should-it-be-worded) to measure the effectiveness of different strategies on an players win percentage.

I would like to know the proper way of expressing the results of my testing. For example, I ran the simulator using two identical random player strategies, with different sample sizes. For each sample size, I ran the simulator 20 times and calculated the Mean and Standard Deviation for each set of 10 thousand - 5 million sample games.

```
      |  Mean  |Std Dev |
      +--------+--------+
   10k|0.495390|0.027331|
   50k|0.502642|0.013702|
  100k|0.500470|0.005940|
  200k|0.501116|0.005152|
  500k|0.502088|0.003186|
1,000k|0.502720|0.001989|
5,000k|0.502542|0.000790|
```

I wanted to use these examples to express how confident I am that later tested strategies are precise to some fixed decimal Win:Loss ratio.

**Can I simply calculate the CI or margin of error (1.96 * Standard Deviation/SQRT(sample size))?**

**Would this mean that I am 95% confident that the true Win:Loss ratio is +/- (sigma/SQRT(n))?**

**Is this the proper way of expressing the precision of simulations results, or is their a more accurate way of expressing precision?**

Answer (score 1):

How you are calculating confidence intervals is correct, and the interpretation of those intervals is that on repeated simulations, 95% of those simulations will fall into the range of the 95% confidence interval. That is subtly different from your interpretation.

Some notes of caution however, in regards to the reporting of large-scale simulation results like this:

1. The notion of a confidence interval is built on the idea of *theoretical random repetitions* of an actual, real-world study. While very useful, for simulation models, you actually have those repetitions. I much prefer a "Simulation Interval", which is the 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles of your results - this gives you a true look at the spread of your results, and does allow you to say things like "95% of the time, the Win:Loss ratio falls into this range".
2. For a single simulation study this is less of a problem, but keep in mind that for simulation studies, statistical power is a function of computational power and patience. This means if you're doing comparison-based testing, it's rather trivial to overpower a study, and detect differences statistically that are meaningless when applied to the real world.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you, the CI values that I calculate would only be in reference to the particular sample (I.e. the random versus random strategies, and not some later strategy using the same number of simulation intervals). Also, the sample size in all the above examples are 20, and not the number of "games"/wins/etc. From the simulation.

Comment: How would I get the 2.5th or 9.5th percentiles? Would that require 200 iterations of the simulation at some number of games (10k-5mil), to get a spread of 200 win:loss ratios.

Comment: @user1873 I'm not sure I really understand your study - if you're only running 20 simulations, where do the number of games come into play?

Comment: I simulate 10k - 5mil hands (I should probably simulate **games** since I am interested in win:loss ratios). I ran the simulation for 10,000 hands 20 times, and calculated three mean amd standard deviation of those win:loss ratios. I did the same for 100k, 5 mil, amd every other value in the chart. Running the simulation 20 times each and calculating the average win:loss ratio amd the standard deviation.

Comment: @user1873 Perhaps a better question - what are you trying to accomplish? An estimate of the precision of the simulations, or an estimate of the win:loss ratio following this particular strategy?

Comment: A measurement of the precision of the simulation. Basically, how many games do I need to play to say that when the simulation reports that **strategy X** wins 0.67458943567653% of the time, to what decimal place can I say that rate is significant? (I.e. 67.4%, 67.46%, 67.459%, etc.)

Comment: Then one thing I would do is run considerably more simulations. N = 20 is a pretty small number to be calculating a CI off of, let alone my suggested simulation interval.

Comment: which I why I said it looks like I need to run it 200 times to get a 2.5th and 97.5th percentile results. I know what the theoretical correct average is here (50%). The Mean win:loss ratio for all tested hands of 10k-5mil were within a quarter of a percent of the correct value, but the STDDEV seemed to decrease by a 1/4 for every factor if 10 increase in the number if hands played.